# Gutenberg change/remove "Write your story" placeholder in custom blocks

Tags: block-editor

When created a new page or post or columns blocks we get the "Write your story" placeholder. Can this be removed or replaced, in custom blocks? How?

[image]

Comment: Sure, but could you post the code you've worked thus far when you tried to get this to work? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @admcfajn there is no code, as far as I know for this, recommended in the Gutenberg docs. I can think of a few hacky ways to remove it but I'm interested in an official way of doing it, and so are many people because it's not documented. That's the point of the question.

Comment: Here's try this out, there's a handful of custom blocks in this repo you can dig into: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-examples/blob/master/03-editable/block.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There does seem to be a filter to modify the default: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/lib/client-assets.php#L1574

```
'bodyPlaceholder'        => apply_filters( 'write_your_story', __( 'Write your story', 'gutenberg' ), $post ),
```

So you should be able to use the WordPress [add_filter()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example block taken from [WordPress/gutenberg-examples](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-examples) with placeholder text added.

```
const { __, setLocaleData } = wp.i18n;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { RichText } = wp.editor;

setLocaleData( window.gutenberg_examples_03_esnext.localeData, 'gutenberg-examples' );

registerBlockType( 'gutenberg-examples/example-03-editable-esnext', {
    title: __( 'Example: Editable (esnext)', 'gutenberg-examples' ),
    icon: 'universal-access-alt',
    category: 'layout',
    attributes: {
        content: {
            type: 'array',
            source: 'children',
            selector: 'p',
        },
    },
    edit: ( props ) => {
        const { attributes: { content }, setAttributes, className } = props;
        const onChangeContent = ( newContent ) => {
            setAttributes( { content: newContent } );
        };
        return (
            <RichText
                tagName="p"
                className={ className }
                onChange={ onChangeContent }
                value={ content }
                placeholder={__('wpse316624 placeholder text', 'custom-block')}
            />
        );
    },
    save: ( props ) => {
        return <RichText.Content tagName="p" value={ props.attributes.content } />;
    },
} );
```

Comment: That's a placeholder for a paragraph richtext element not the initial block placeholder. Answer should be removed.

Comment: I agree with you CyberJ, but since Gutenberg is still pretty new I'll leave it up just in case it helps point someone in the right direction.