# Remove 'type / to choose a block' placeholder

Tags: block-editor

I'd like to remove the placeholder in an empty block 'type / to choose a block'.

I often have empty spaces in my drafts as I'm writing and this placeholder clutters everything. I'd just like it empty. Is there a way to remove it with a filter?

Comment: Looks  like this has been asked before here: [Gutenberg change/remove "Write your story" placeholder in custom blocks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/316624/gutenberg-change-remove-write-your-story-placeholder-in-custom-blocks)

Comment: No, these are 2 separate questions. The "Write your story" placeholder shows in a new post when no blocks have been added. The solutions for that question do not solve my problem. My question above is the place holder in a paragraph block when there is no text.

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter( 'write_your_story', function ( $string, $post ){ return ' '; }, 10,2);
```

Also answered at: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-type-to-choose-a-block-block-placeholder/

Docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/write_your_story/

Comment: Adding the filter modifies the new post placeholder, not the paragraph block placeholder in my question above. The CSS on that wordpress post doesn't remove the placeholder text but does hide it successfully.